# TableView Cell video autoplay

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitableview

**What I had done :-**

> I had added the code which plays a video when cell is fully visible
>   and when I scrolls down or up it reload the tableview again and plays
>   video again. But, my requirement is different.

**What I actually want :**

> I want to play a video untill the backward or forward cell fully
>   visible. When user scroll downs or up it doesn’t affect untill the
>   backward or forward cell fully visible.

**Design**

```
Table Cell Layout Description
-> Video Table Cell (Fix height 393) 
    -> Content View
    -> Main view - (as per Content view of Table view Cell)
        -> Title View (0, 0, MainView.width, 57)
        -> Video View (0, 57, MainView.width, 200);
        -> Description View (0, 257, MainView.width, 136)
```

**Coding :**

> VideoTableCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>



@interface VideoTableCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewForVideo;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgThumb;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnPlay;

@property (strong, nonatomic) AVPlayerItem* videoItem;

@property (strong, nonatomic) AVPlayer* videoPlayer;

@property (strong, nonatomic) AVPlayerLayer* avLayer;



@end
```

> VideoTableCell.m

```
#import "VideoTableCell.h"

@implementation VideoTableCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    return self;
}
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
     [self.avLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(self.viewForVideo.frame.origin.x, self.viewForVideo.frame.origin.y, self.viewForVideo.frame.size.width,  self.viewForVideo.frame.size.height)];

}

@end
```

> VideoVC.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface VideoVC : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tblData;

@end
```

> VideoVC.m

```
#import "VideoVC.h"

#import "VideoTableCell.h"



@interface VideoVC ()

{
    NSArray *arrVideo ;
    bool isScrolling;
    int index;
BOOL fullvisible ;

}
@end  

@implementation VideoVC

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];    

    arrVideo = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"http://video/1.mp4",@"http://video/2.mp4", @"http://video/3.mp4", @"http://video/4.mp4", @"http://video/5.mp4", nil];

    fullvisible = YES;   
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return arrVideo.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    VideoTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"VideoTableCell"];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"VideoTableCell" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    int temp =  [self getVisibleIndex];

    if (temp == indexPath.row && fullvisible)
    {
            cell.imgThumb.hidden = YES ;
            //NSLog(@"fullvisible == 1");
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[arrVideo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

            cell.videoItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
            cell.videoPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:cell.videoItem];
            cell.avLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:cell.videoPlayer];

            [cell.avLayer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
            // [cell.avLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
            [cell.contentView.layer addSublayer:cell.avLayer];
            [cell.videoPlayer play];

            [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    }
    else
    {
            cell.imgThumb.hidden = NO ;
            cell.videoPlayer = nil;
            [cell.avLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
            cell.videoItem = nil;
            [cell.videoPlayer pause];
    }
    return cell ;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 393 ;
}


-(int)getVisibleIndex

{   
    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in _tblData.indexPathsForVisibleRows) {

        CGRect cellRect = [_tblData rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        BOOL isVisible = CGRectContainsRect(_tblData.bounds, cellRect);

        if (isVisible)

        {
            index = (int)indexPath.row ;
        }
    }
    return index ;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView

{

    NSArray* cells = _tblData.visibleCells;

    for (VideoTableCell* cell in cells)

    {

            NSIndexPath *path = [_tblData indexPathForCell:cell] ;

            index =(int) path.row;

            fullvisible = YES;

            [_tblData reloadData];

    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe by setting the `actionAtItemEnd` to pause, checking with KVO the status of pause, checking if `player.currentTime == player.currentItem.duration` (that's what you want), and playing next item if that's the case. In other words, creating a micro-pause between items...

Comment: Try this answer:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831485/best-way-to-check-if-uitableviewcell-is-completely-visible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831485/best-way-to-check-if-uitableviewcell-is-completely-visible)

Answer (score 17):

Every `UITableViewCell` subclass has a method `prepareForReuse:` so in your `VideoTableCell` just add a method:

```
-(void)prepareForReuse {
   [super prepareForReuse];
   [self.videoPlayer play];
}
```

And in your controller implement a delegate method: `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   [cell stopVideo];
}
```

and in `stopVideo` just add `[self.videoPlayer pause]` or `[cell.videoPlayer stop]`

Answer (score 5):

try this methods in UITableView

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // stop video
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // play video
}
```

should help you.

If this will not fully work for your requirements try override `scrollViewDidScroll`
[more details there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9833241/1157124)

Answer (score -2):

Write a category for UITableViewCell to check if the cell is fully visible:

## UITableViewCell+FullyVisible

```
 -(BOOL) isFullyVisible {

UITableView *tableview = (UITableView *)[self parents:[UITableView class]];
CGRect rect = [tableview rectForRowAtIndexPath:[tableview indexPathForCell:self]];
rect = [tableview convertRect:rect toView:tableview.superview];
return CGRectContainsRect(tableview.frame, rect);
}
```

And in *cellForRowAtIndexpath:* check if cell is fully visible. If cell is fully visible play video else stop/pause.